# Add a subcategory in a PreferenceCategory

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is there a way to add subcategories to a PreferenceCategory?

This isn't possible:

```
 PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    setPreferenceScreen(preferenceScreen);

    PreferenceCategory superCategory= new PreferenceCategory(this);
    preferenceScreen.addPreference(superCategory);

    PreferenceCategory subCategory= new PreferenceCategory(this);
    superCategory.addPreference(subCategory);
```

Because you "cannot add a preferencecategory directly to a preferencecategory"

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file, you *can* in fact add a PreferenceCategory to a PreferenceCategory. However, the results are not all that satisfactory:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Appearance">

        <ListPreference 
            app:title="Number of Results"
            android:key="no_of_results"
            android:entries="@array/noOfResults"
            android:entryValues="@array/noOfResultsValues"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            />

        <ListPreference 
            app:title="Theme"
            android:summary=""
            android:key="theme"
            android:entries="@array/theme"
            android:entryValues="@array/themeValues"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            />



        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Subcategory">

            <Preference android:title="Preference"/>

        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

On doing this, you get this kind of a result: [PreferenceScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIbOL.png). As you can see here, though, the hierarchy is not visible.

Comment: If that made no visual difference and this is not the solution why did you post it as an answer?